# Query is very slow when I add a third LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi there I have been playing with this query hours and I can't get it return results in a reasonable execution time.

Here is the case:

I have three tables -

Table 1 called : `rowsall`

```
 1  id          int(11) 
 2  masterCaseId    varchar(50)
 3  RowNum  int(11)
 4  fullCaseNumber  varchar(50)
 5  rowKtavNameFull varchar(250)
 6  DateOpen    varchar(50)
 7  DateProccess    varchar(50)
 8  rowStatus   varchar(50)
 9  rowCourt    varchar(100)
 10 rowProcedure    varchar(50)
 11 rowCaseType varchar(50)
 12 rowIntrest  varchar(50)
 13 rowDetailsGen   varchar(250)
 14 rowTypeTeanot   varchar(50)
 15 rowHisayon  varchar(50)
 16 rowAmount   varchar(50)
 17 rowZacautPtor   varchar(50)
 18 rowZacautApproove   varchar(50)
 19 rowStatIravon   varchar(50)
 20 rowDateClose    varchar(50)
 21 rowCloseReason  varchar(50)
 22 rowResultTaken  varchar(50)
 23 rowOldFile          varchar(50)
 24 rowOpenedInCourse   varchar(50)
 25 rowGniza            varchar(50)
 26 rowReasonDeposit    varchar(50)
 27 rowTypeJudgeType    varchar(50)
 28 rowJudgeTypeDate
 29 rowJudgeTypeName    varchar(50)
 30 rowGishurType   varchar(50)
 31 rowGishurDetails    varchar(250)

   Total rows: 13001, size 11.7mb

   Indexes:
   PRIMARY  BTREE   Yes No  id  13001   A   No  
   RowNum   BTREE   No  No  RowNum  12  A   No  
                            rowStatus   12  A   No
                            rowResultTaken  12  A   No
   rowJudgeTypeName BTREE   No  No  rowJudgeTypeName    1083    A   No  
   masterCaseId BTREE   No  No  masterCaseId    13001   A   No  
   RowNum_2 BTREE   No  No  rowJudgeTypeName    1857    A   No  
                            RowNum  1857    A   No
   fullCaseNumber   BTREE   No  No  fullCaseNumber  203 A   No
```

Table 2 called : `casses_rows`

```
 1  id  int(11)
 2  caseFullNum varchar(50)
 3  statusCrawl varchar(50)
 4  courtPlace  text
 5  rowsNum int(11)
 6  caseJudge   varchar(50)
 7  caseFullName    text
 8  whenCrawled datetime
 9  yearVal varchar(5)
 10 monthVal    varchar(5)
 11 caseVal int(11)

   Total rows: ~23,846, size 4.8mb

   Indexes:
   PRIMARY  BTREE   Yes No  id  26302   A   No
```

Table 3 called : `casedocs`

```
 1  id  int(11)
 2  caseNum varchar(20)
 3  DocTitle    varchar(250)
 4  DocDateStr  varchar(20)
 5  KeyWords    text
 6  content text
 7  DocDateParsed   timestamp

   Total rows: ~1,163,669, size 4.1g

   Indexes:
   PRIMARY  BTREE   Yes No  id  895132  A   No  
   caseNum  BTREE   No  No  caseNum 895132  A   No
```

**My goal:**

I need to join those tables to get most of the cols in table1 + one col in table 2 + one col in table 3 or NULL if there is no match:

**My Query is:**

```
SELECT 
       A.`id` AS idRowCase, 
       C.`caseNum` AS isPaperAva, 
       A.`rowCaseType`, 
       A.`fullCaseNumber`, 
       A.`rowProcedure`, 
       B.`caseFullName`, 
       A.`rowCourt`, 
       A.`rowAmount`, 
       A.`rowResultTaken`, A.`rowStatus`, A.`rowIntrest` ,A.`DateOpen` ,A.`DateProccess`, A.`rowDateClose`, A.`rowJudgeTypeDate` 

FROM (SELECT * FROM `rowsall` WHERE `rowJudgeTypeName` LIKE '%@value1%' AND `RowNum` ='1' ) A 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT `id`,`caseFullName` FROM `casses_rows` ) B 
      ON A.`masterCaseId` = B.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `caseNum` FROM `casedocs` GROUP BY `caseNum` ORDER BY NULL ) C 
      ON A.`fullCaseNumber` = C.`caseNum`
```

The result is as I wanted, but the problem is that it takes **1 min** to return the results...

**Here is the EXPLAIN:**

```
  id   select_type  table       type   possible_keys  key     key_len  ref  rows   Extra
  1    PRIMARY      <derived2>  ALL    NULL           NULL    NULL     NULL 121
  1    PRIMARY      <derived3>  ALL    NULL           NULL    NULL     NULL 24185  Using where; Using join buffer
  1    PRIMARY      <derived4>  ALL    NULL           NULL    NULL     NULL 343438
  4    DERIVED      casedocs    index  NULL           caseNum 62       NULL 768024 Using index
  3    DERIVED      casses_rows ALL    NULL           NULL    NULL     NULL 29872  
  2    DERIVED      rowsall     ref    RowNum         RowNum  4             6500   Using where
```

As you can see I'm grouping table 3 to prevent the join creating duplicate rows in the results - actually the third join is to test if there are docs that correspond to the case or not (will be NULL).

**More information:**

- If I remove the third join the query take **1 sec**
- If I execute only the third join select statement it take **0.003 sec**.
- When profiling the query the " sending data " is 99.9% of the time.

Any Ideas why it takes so long to execute the third join????

**Mission accomplished!**
Thanks to @Turophile and @Joel Coehoorn new test results are arount 0.004 sec!!!

Here is the finall query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.`id` AS idRowCase, C.`caseNum` AS isPaperAva, A.`rowCaseType` ,  A.`fullCaseNumber` , A.`rowProcedure` , B.`caseFullName` , A.`rowCourt` , A.`rowAmount` , A.`rowResultTaken` , A.`rowStatus` , A.`rowIntrest` , A.`DateOpen` , A.`DateProccess` , A.`rowDateClose` , A.`rowJudgeTypeDate` 

FROM  `rowsall` A
INNER JOIN  `casses_rows` B ON A.`masterCaseId` = B.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `casedocs` C ON A.`fullCaseNumber` = C.`caseNum` 
WHERE A.`rowJudgeTypeName` LIKE  '%@value1%'
AND A.`RowNum` =  '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the first two tables have no need for subqueries at all. This can be better expressed directly through join conditions and the WHERE clause.

Also, the last join uses a sub query with a group by:

> LEFT JOIN (SELECT `caseNum` FROM `casedocs` GROUP BY `caseNum` ORDER BY NULL )

This breaks MySql's ability to use any indexes when computing that last join. If you can re-write this to join the table first, and do the GROUP BY in the outer query, so that you get the same results, it might perform *much* better, because you'll have better use of indexes.

```
SELECT 
       A.`id` AS idRowCase, 
       C.`caseNum` AS isPaperAva, 
       A.`rowCaseType`, 
       A.`fullCaseNumber`, 
       A.`rowProcedure`, 
       B.`caseFullName`, 
       A.`rowCourt`, 
       A.`rowAmount`, 
       A.`rowResultTaken`, A.`rowStatus`, A.`rowIntrest` ,A.`DateOpen` ,A.`DateProccess`, A.`rowDateClose`, A.`rowJudgeTypeDate` 

FROM `rowsall` A 
INNER JOIN `casses_rows` B   ON A.`masterCaseId` = B.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `caseNum` FROM `casedocs` GROUP BY `caseNum` ) C ON c.`caseNum` = A.`fullCaseNumber`
WHERE A.`rowJudgeTypeName` LIKE '%@value1%' AND A.`RowNum` ='1'
```

Comment: Hi there unfortunately droping the third table is not producing the results I'm after - as I wrote in the question the third table actually is joind (LEFT JOIN) to the result just for checking if there are docs related to the casenumber - if he will find results then there will be a value otherwise it will be NULL... I have to GROUP or DISTINCT it because there may be a lot of docs related to the same casenumber and I want to check only if there is or not - if I don't group I will have a lot of duplicates results that I can't group after....

Comment: Why GROUP BY prevent the index use?

Comment: I tried your edited query (without sub-queries) and it took more time this time 1.5 min.

Comment: Finally its working thank you - I merged your answer with @Turophile answer and got it to work as fast as i can imagine 0.0046 sec - the main problem was the group by issue and removing the sub-queries boosted it too.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to not sort and group unnecessarily. So, something like this:

```
SELECT 
   A.`id` AS idRowCase, 
   C.`caseNum` AS isPaperAva, 
   A.`rowCaseType`, 
   A.`fullCaseNumber`, 
   A.`rowProcedure`, 
   B.`caseFullName`, 
   A.`rowCourt`, 
   A.`rowAmount`, 
   A.`rowResultTaken`, 
   A.`rowStatus`, 
   A.`rowIntrest`,
   A.`DateOpen` ,
   A.`DateProccess`, 
   A.`rowDateClose`, 
   A.`rowJudgeTypeDate` 

FROM `rowsall` AS A 
INNER JOIN `casses_rows` AS B 
      ON A.`masterCaseId` = B.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `casedocs` AS C 
      ON A.`fullCaseNumber` = C.`caseNum`
WHERE `rowJudgeTypeName` LIKE '%@value1%' 
AND   `RowNum` ='1'
```

(may return different results (multiple rows) if caseNum isn't unique).

You could also turn the `LEFT JOIN` into a sub-select:

```
SELECT 
   A.`id` AS idRowCase, 
   A.`fullCaseNumber` AS isPaperAva, 
   A.`rowCaseType`, 
   A.`fullCaseNumber`, 
   A.`rowProcedure`, 
   B.`caseFullName`, 
   A.`rowCourt`, 
   A.`rowAmount`, 
   A.`rowResultTaken`, 
   A.`rowStatus`, 
   A.`rowIntrest`,
   A.`DateOpen` ,
   A.`DateProccess`, 
   A.`rowDateClose`, 
   A.`rowJudgeTypeDate` 

FROM `rowsall` AS A 
INNER JOIN `casses_rows` AS B 
      ON A.`masterCaseId` = B.`id` 
WHERE `rowJudgeTypeName` LIKE '%@value1%' 
AND   `RowNum` ='1' 
AND   A.`fullCaseNumber` in (SELECT `caseNum` FROM `casedocs` )
```

But this shows that using table `casedocs` is kind of redundant - is it really needed?

Comment: Hi there unfortunately droping the third table is not producing the results I'm after - as I wrote in the question the third table actually is joind (LEFT JOIN) to the result just for checking if there are docs related to the casenumber - if he will find results then there will be a value otherwise it will be NULL... I have to GROUP or DISTINCT it because there may be a lot of docs related to the same casenumber and I want to check only if there is or not - if I don't group I will have a lot of duplicates results that I can't group after....

Comment: unbelievable I added one word to your solution and now it works!!!! 0.0046 sec!!!!! but i can't accept your answer because the problem was found by @Joel_Coehoorn it was the group by issue at the end and removing the sub queries boosted it to but mainly the group by.

Comment: Glad I could help. Note that your final query is clear and simple - when you are having difficulties, try to make your SQL clearer and simpler - it usually helps.